# CSS: define font-weight by name

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm wondering if there would be a way to define an @font-face's weight with a string rather than just a number:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('../fonts/MyFont/light.eot');
    …
    font-weight: 'light', 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('../fonts/MyFont/thin.eot');
    …
    font-weight: 'thin', 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I'm thinking it would be easier for someone breaking out a design into code if the weights matched (eg in Photoshop the font's weight will be *light*, not *300*).

After reading the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness), it sounds like they do intend you to match the names to a number, but that seems asinine, so I assume I'm missing something.

Comment: You could look into something like LESS or SCSS, both of which allow you to define variables to represent CSS data, like `$light: 300;` and using that like `font-weight: $light;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS2.1 spec which you link to only defines a specific set of keywords corresponding to specific numerical values. It doesn't say anything about allowing authors to define keywords for numerical values, whether in a current or future spec.

Along with numerical values, the only keywords you can specify with the [`font-weight` descriptor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop-desc) in `@font-face` rules are `normal` and `bold` (whereas `bolder` and `lighter` are relative values and so can't be specified). Even if it allowed you to specify custom keywords, the `font-weight` property would have to be re-specced to allow those custom keywords and browsers would have to recognize those custom keywords, which they don't.

Comment: Darn, I can't imagine why they don't let you do both considering no-one actually refers to a font's weight by a number.

Comment: The statement “The `font-weight` descriptor in `@font-face` rules only lets you specify fonts for the `normal` and `bold` keywords”. The numeric weights from 100 to 900 are also allowed.

Comment: @Jukka: Indeed, that was misleading. I edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

There are four strings you can use to define `font-weight`: `normal`, `bold`, `bolder`, and `lighter`, the second two being relative to the weight of the parent. It's all described in the spec that you linked to.

If you want to make your own and use a preprocessor, you could create variables for your weights and have as many as you want.

**Sass**

**variables.scss.css**

```
$verythin: 100;
$thin: 200;
$medium: 300;
$thick: 500;
$unnecessarilybold: 600;
```

**main.scss.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('../fonts/MyFont/thin.eot');
    …
    font-weight: $thin;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for next-best solution. I did want to refer to the weights by name in the actual css. Too bad it's not allowed :/

Answer (score 2):

It was a design decision in CSS to use numbers from 100 to 900 rather than names. The basic reason behind this is that the use of names among font manufacturers is not consistent.

You cannot define any symbolic names in CSS. This, too, is an intentional design decision: CSS is a style sheet language, not a programming language.

In practice, most fonts that you encounter in the wild, as fonts commonly available in people’s computers or as free fonts that you can legally use as downloadable fonts, have only two weights, 400 and 700, which have predefined symbolic names. So the issue is practically not very relevant. E.g., when using the minority of Google fonts that have other weights, Google informs you about the numeric weight to be used. (And this is really just a convention in this case; you could use any number, as long as you are consistent – it’s the actual typeface that matters.)